# Bootstrap Image fit to screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to scale image to browser screen using bootstrap, just like [this](http://www.northrupphotography.com/) website.

By setting

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

it does show full image, but shows scrolls as well.
Scrolls are being countered through:

```
body {
     overflow-y: hidden;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Now, the problem is, I am unable to show complete image on screen. It does crop some portion of image (in case image is bigger than browser window).

Anyone to help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should restrict the Width and Height of the image to screen size.

**I notice that instead of using `min-width` and `min-height` properties, you are using `max-width` and `max-height`**

Check out the **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMJY3/)**

Try the following code :

```
body {
  background:url("images/your_image.jpg");      // Your Image URL
  min-height : 100%;
  min-width : 100%;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

You can find it here : **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DMJY3/)**

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 5):

`Bootstrap`has the built-in [`img-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) class for this purpose. This applies `max-width: 100%;, height: auto; and display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/flickr/5661878892_15fba42846_o.jpg" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying this morning a bit and I finally got it to work.

Below is the code:

```
body {
    background: url('/yourimage.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
<img src="images/your-image.jpg" class="vh-100 vw-100" />
```